# exception handling in the api

Tags: java, exception

I have a java interface that has a method as below -

```
List<TalkDO> process() throws DurationException;
```

DurationException is unchecked exception.

I am writing an implementation for this function where I read data from a file and process each line one by one. File read in requires to handle FileNotFoundException and IOException. I have to throw this exception to caller and to let it know that these 2 exception has occered but throwing this exception will make it like

```
List<TalkDO> process() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
```

Which is not allowed in java. What could be my approach, I dont want to catch and handle IOException and FileNotFoundException in my process method

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Why do you think specifying multiple exceptions to method signature in interface *is not allowed in java* ??

Comment: "which is not allowed in java" -did you test your code?

Comment: It is saying process()' in 'FileInputProcessor' clashes with 'process()' in 'InputProcessor'; overridden method does not throw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException;

Comment: why its not allowed?

Comment: Have you other implementations ?  For example implementations that don't use file ?

Comment: yes, I do have implementations that does not use file

Comment: Change the signature of the method of the interface, or catch and rethrow the IOException as an unchecked exception (an UncheckedIOException, for example). Make sure to wrap the original IOException to have a meaningful stack trace. You can also rethrow it as a DurationException if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As you have multiple implementations of your interface and according to your comments some don't use `File`, I think that providing an interface that specifies exceptions of every implementations may be cumbersome for clients.
Why force a client to catch  `FileNotFoundException` if he uses an implementation that cannot throw it?
A more flexible way would be to declare only throwing runtime exceptions in `List<TalkDO> process()`.

In your implementation, you should catch checked exceptions and re-throw 
a `RuntimeException` version of them.
In this way, each client will catch the exception he needs to.

**Interface**

```
public MyInterface {
   public List<TalkDO> process() throws DurationException, IORuntimeException, FileNotFoundRuntimeException
}
```

**Implementation using File**

```
public MyFileImpl implements MyInterface{
   public List<TalkDO> process() throws DurationException, IORuntimeException, FileNotFoundRuntimeException{
       ...
      try{

      }
      catch (IOException e){
         throw new IORuntimeException("your msg", e);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e){
         throw new FileNotFoundRuntimeException("your msg", e);
      }
   }
```

**Implementation without using File**

```
public MyInMemoryImpl implements MyInterface{
   public List<TalkDO> process() throws DurationException {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: so far, thats what i also think

Answer (score 0):

> throws DurationException, IOException, FileNotFoundException is not
>   allowed in Java

This is not correct, you can specify multiple exceptions in the method signature using the `throws` clause, you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) on this.

Also, one important point is that it is not good practice to specify the **unchecked exceptions** (like your `DurationException`) in the method signature, it will make the method signature to clutter, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) for more details.

> What could be my approach, I don't want to catch and handle IOException
>   and FileNotFoundException in my process method

You either have to catch or throw the checked exceptions and say if you don't want to propagate these exceptions as checked exceptions to the caller, you can wrap these checked exceptions into unchecked (runtime exceptions).

> It is saying process()' in 'FileInputProcessor' clashes with
>   'process()' in 'InputProcessor'; overridden method does not throw
>   'java.io.FileNotFoundException

The important point about Java exceptions is that you can't **throw new checked exceptions from the overriding methods**, so you need to convert them into unchecked/`RuntimeException` objects. So, the solution is in your implementation class, you need to **wrap the checked exception and throw a `new` `RuntimeExcetion`** (just create your own custom `BusinessException` i.e., project specific).

Comment: agreed about DurationException but throwing other 2 exceptions is not workin

Comment: It is saying process()' in 'FileInputProcessor' clashes with 'process()' in 'InputProcessor'; overridden method does not throw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException